# Implement a Silverlight proxy client?

Tags: proxy, silverlight-4.0

Is it possible in Silverlight to create a proxy client, meaning the Silverlight application knows the host, port, username and password of the proxy server, then establishes a connection to the proxy server?

The Silverlight application would then be able to issues HTTP requests to resources behind that proxy server.

This way, the Silverlight application would reach certain resources without having to install a thirdparty proxy client on the client-machine first, because the proxy client would be part of the Silverlight application itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the WebClient to issue HTTP requests from Silverlight.

WebClient has a Proxy property, but not in Silverlight.

So I made a webservice, that takes an url and some proxy-server information. The webservice uses the WebClient and the Proxy property to direct the HTTP request to the proxy-server.

Then the Silverlight application calls that webservice, gives it an url and some proxy-server information.